# Using Sed to delete lines which contain non alphabets

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The following Regex works as expected in Notepad++:

```
^.*[^a-z\r\n].*$
```

However, when I try to use it with sed, it wont work.

```
sed -r 's/\(^.*[^a-z\r\n].*$\)//g' wordlist.txt
```

Comment: `\r` and `\n` does not occur in default behavior of sed that works line by line. You need to load the file in buffer first if wanted in pattern (not in this case). `\r` and `\n` could be replaced by `$` (but not in the class) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
sed -i '/[^a-z]/d' wordlist.txt
```

This will delete each line that has a non-alphabet character (no need to specify linefeeds)

EDIT:

You regex doesn't work because you are trying to match

```
( bracket
^ beginning of line
...
$ end of line
) bracket
```

As you won't have a bracket and then the beginning of the line, your regex simply doesn't match anything.

Note, also an expression of

```
s/\(^.*[^a-z\r\n].*$\)//g'
```

wouldn't delete a line but replace it with a blank line

EDIT2:

Note, in sed using the -r flag changes the behaviour of `\(` and `\)` without the `-r` flag they are group indicators, but with the `-r` flag they're just brackets...

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Sed is a stream editor. It processes one line of the input at a time. That means the search and replace commands, etc, can only see the current line. By contrast, Notepad++ has the whole file in memory and so its search expressions can span two or more lines.

Your command `sed -r 's/\(^.*[^a-z\r\n].*$\)//g' wordlist.txt` includes `\(` and `\)`. These mean real (ie non-escaped) round brackets. So the command says find a line that starts with a `(` and ends with a `)` with some other characters between and replace it with nothing. Rewriting the command as `sed -r 's/^.*[^a-z\r\n].*$//g' wordlist.txt` should have the desired effect. You could also remove the `\r\n` to give `sed -r 's/^.*[^a-z].*$//g' wordlist.txt`. But neither of these will be exactly the same as the Notepad++ command as they will leave empty lines. So you may find the command `sed -r '/^.*[^a-z].*$/d' wordlist.txt` is closer to what you really want.